# AWS codebuild - does disconnecting from Github in single build project remove from all projects

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codebuild

I have multiple Codebuild projects in an AWS account (which were created by others), with private Github repos as the source, connected via oauth.

I'm creating a new Codebuild project, also looking at a private github repo, however Codebuild fails to create since it "can't access the github repo".

I imagine that whoever in the account originally connected to Github, they don't have access to my the repo I'm trying to connect to.

I'd like to click the "disconnect from Github" and re-authorize, since I have access to the repo I'm trying to connect to, but I'm concerned that will disconnect *all* Codebuild projects.

I know that my Github credentials don't permit access to all repos that Codebuild projects are currently reading from.

When a connection to Github is made via oauth, does that set it for the entire account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a connection to Github is made via oauth, does that set it for the entire account?

Yes it will reset the token for all your CodeBuild projects in that AWS account Id. CodeBuild only supports one token (OAuth or personal access token) per AWS account Id.

We are aware of the limitation this causes on end users and will make this experience better in a future release.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this is the same behavior with Codepipeline?

Comment: @tkwargs CodePipeline has a separate token for each source action. Re-connecting one source action will not affect others.

Comment: It's been a couple of years since this answer, does anyone know if this limitation is still the case? I haven't been able to figure it out from documentation elsewhere.